# How to find two difference number values between A1 and B1 less than or equal to 10 value in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to find two difference number values between A1 and B2 less than or equal to 10 value in Excel. If

For example: (If A1 and B1 Difference Value is Less than or equal to 10, the value of C may be displayed in Result column)

A    B    C       Result 
1  10   22   15       15

Answer (score 2):

Show C1 if less than or equal to 10, otherwise show D1:

```
=IF(ABS(A1-B1) <= 10, C1, D1)
```

Show C1 if less than or equal to 10, otherwise show nothing:

```
=IF(ABS(A1-B1) <= 10, C1)
```

Show C1 if less than or equal to 10, otherwise show something else:

```
=IF(ABS(A1-B1) <= 10, C1, "Something else")
```